# Different Schema for iOS App in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: ios, xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on a KMM project and I need to create different Schema for my project eg (Dev, Production, QA) I can easily do it in android part but I am not able to create the same in iOS. I tried creating different schemas normally we do in iOS app but my app crashes with the error targeting to our `packForXcode` task in android studio.

Error while crash :- `No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.NativeBuildType.DEVELOPMENT`  Here I have created a custom schema named `development`

This error points to

```
val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
group = "build"
val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
inputs.property("mode", mode)
dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
from({ framework.outputDirectory })
into(targetDir)
}
```

Now into `binaries` I can see that there are two `NativeBuildTargets`  `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` so I can run in both of these but how can I create a custom schema for my iOS app ?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the `mode` variable containing `"configuration"` value, which is not an appropriate build type from the Kotlin/Native compiler point of view(see some details in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-build-native-binaries.html)). To avoid it, one should redefine the function determining `mode`s value. For example, it might be something like that:

```
val mode = if (System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") != "release") "DEBUG" else System.getenv("CONFIGURATION")
```

Comment: What if i use `kotlin("native.cocoapods")`, and how i can re-assign the `configuration` value?

Comment: There is a problem with custom build names and the Cocoapods plugin. Please see [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42023) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me

```
val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    // Below line is important to solve it
    val mode = if (System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") != "release") "DEBUG" else System.getenv("CONFIGURATION")
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
```